# Numpy array with repeating pattern

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting, numpy-ndarray

How do you create a `1 x n` array in NumPy following an incrementing pattern?

For example:

`[0, 5, 10, 15, ... (n-1)*5]`

Comment: `np.arange(n) * 5` where you `import numpy as np` first

Comment: Or `np.arange(0, N+1, 5)`

Comment: Should your example output be `[0, 5, 10, 15, ... (n-1)*5]`? What you currently have doesn't make complete sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.arange` is the correct answer (as pointed out in the comments). For completeness, here's a list of simple 1-liners that will produce the desired array:

- `np.arange(n)*5`
- `np.arange(0, n*5, 5)`
- `np.linspace(0, (n-1)*5, n, dtype=int)`
- `np.array(range(0, n*5, 5))`

For example, if `n=7` then all of the above will produce the array:

```
[ 0  5 10 15 20 25 30]
```